# error when installing app in release mode

Tags: android-studio

784/5000
I have created an app with the default template that brings android studio: Navegation Drawer Activity without adding more code.
I have changed it to release mode, and I have introduced a key, now it is ready to upload it to the play store.
I have compiled it and it has not produced an error. I have generated the apk and I have tried to install it in emulator nox player version of android 4.4.2 that corresponds to api 19 where all the app in debug mode have always worked.
Version sdk api 19 min to api 27
When I install it I get an error but it does not give me any message explaining why it is not installed.
My version of android studio is 3.1.2
If the apk is installed in another android emulator 7.0 api 24 if I install it and it works perfectly.
Why is not it installed in the emulator nox player api 4.4.2?

Comment: I have already solved the problem, I found the solution in this post   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54630/instalar-apk-generada-por-android-studio

Comment: prepare the app to release the signature key and enter password and alias it is necessary to indicate the two boxes V1 jar and V2 apk and compile and it works correctly it has not given me any error again.